Question about VACF from MD simulation
I have several LAMMPS NVT MD simulations at several different constant temperatures, for some crystals and amorphous materials, all of them are 3D periodic bulk system. All of them have 10k iterations. My goal is to get VACF and then VDOS.
I get time vs VACF curve using my code. I used the equation:
$$c(t)=\frac{1}{N+1}\sum_{t_{0}=0}^{N}v(t+t_{0})\cdot v(t_{0})$$
where N = total number of XYZ trajectory frames - t/dt, from following referenecs:
https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/566473/how-to-calculate-the-velocity-autocorrelation-function-in-a-molecular-dynamics-s
and
Calculating Velocity autocorrelation function for Binary Diffusion Coefficient
From there, I can get normalized VACF by c(t)/c(0).
But I found that other references for different c(t) description. Wang et al., 2021, omput Phys Commun. used:
$$ c(t)=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{N}\left<v_{i}(t)\cdot v_{i}(0) \right>}{\sum_{i=1}^{N}(v_{i}(0))^2}$$
This is normalized c(t) description, but I think this expression is little strange.
And also I find following from Haberlandt et al., Chapter 10. Simulation of Microporous Systems: Confined Fluids in Equilibrium and Diffusion in Zeolites, Handbook of Surfaces and Interfaces of Materials
$$c(t)=\frac{1}{M}\sum_{M}^{\nu =1}\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^{N}v_{i}(t_{\nu })\cdot v_{i}(t_{\nu }-\triangle t)$$
I normalized this by c(t)/c(0)
I tried them all, and compared normalized VACF, then I found all VACF vs. time curves are different... I thought they all should be the same, but I couldn't figure out why they are different. Am I doing something wrong with my script?
Thanks

What do you mean "iterations" in this context?

The second question was deleted to comply with the "one question per post" policy.

@AndreyPoletayev iteration = MD iteration number = MD steps = number of frames = number of configurations. My timestep dt was 1.0fs, BTW.

Your third formula is one estimator for the velocity autocovariance function (uncentered).
Your first formula appears to estimate the same thing, but without knowing how the atomic velocities $v_i$ are processed into $v$, the ... average velocity? it is impossible to say why you might have a different answer.
Your second formula estimates the velocity autocorrelation function.
To understand the difference, consider the usual statistical definitions. The (centred) covariance of two random variables A and B measures how much the expectation value of their product differs from the product of their expectations values:
$$ \mathrm{cov}_{AB} \equiv \langle A B \rangle - \langle A \rangle \langle B \rangle. \tag{1} $$
The covariance has units (of A times B) and scales (if A doubles, its covariance with B also doubles). Their (Pearson) correlation is the covariance divided by both their standard deviations:
$$ \rho_{AB} \equiv \frac{\mathrm{cov}_{A B}}{\sigma_A \sigma_B} \tag{2} $$
The correlation is unitless and confined between -1 and +1; its square is the coefficient of determination ($R^2$) of linear regression.
Here's the rub: some disciplines say "autocorrelation" for the covariance between a variable and its lagged self. Some disciplines say "autocovariance" for the lagged covariance and "autocorrelation" for the lagged correlation. Physicists aren't always consistent, but I've almost always seen the "velocity autocorrelation function" mean the lagged covariance (it doesn't help that "VACF" is ambiguous!).
But which one is correct? It depends on the application! At the end of the day, you have to look at what you're trying to derive and work out if the autocovariance or autocorrelation is called for. For example, the Green-Kubo relation says that the (linear) transport coefficient equals the long-time integral of the autocovariance of the corresponding gross variable's time derivative.

The autocorrelation time is incredibly useful to calculate in this context:
$$ \tau \equiv \int_{\Delta t = 0}^\infty \langle \rho_{A(t), A(t+\Delta t)} \rangle \mathrm{d}\Delta t \tag{3} $$
It's the area under the autocorrelation curve, and it usefully answers the question of "how many uncorrelated samples do I have in my trajectory?" Which in turn answers the fundamental question of how often one needs snapshots -- for example, taking snapshots every 10 nanoseconds probably gives twice the information of snapshots every 5 nanoseconds, but snapshots every 10 femtoseconds probably do not give twice the information of snapshots every 5 femtoseconds!
In this context, the algorithms for calculating autocorrelation time on this page are well worth reading. In particular, the page (which cites a source!!) recommends calculating the autocorrelation time by calculating the autocorrelation function and integrating it, not to $\Delta t = \infty$, but to a $\Delta t$ stopping at $5 \tau$.
This makes sense: $\tau$ is effectively an exponential decay time of the autocorrelation, and an exponential decay of $5\tau$ is usually sufficient to say the decaying thing is effectively gone. Thus, the autocorrelation function is completely noise past $5\tau$, having ever larger extreme values due to shrinking sample size, and holds no remaining mathematical information.

Thanks for the reference of ACT. For my case, I have LAMMPS NVT MD result XYZ trajectory files. Timestep dt = 1.0fs and I printed all trajectories for each 1fs. I have vx vy vz estimated by lammps dump (I think these are instataneous vx vy vz of each atom), and I also have vx vy vz calculated from xyz of t and t+1 by 1fs time step. In my case I just used 1fs time step of MD simulation & xyz print frequency setting, but maybe I need to look into ACT. Thanks.

I have 10k MD steps (=10k frames = 10k trajectories) with 1fs time step.
So, you're saying that, I need to test various VACF values by trying various delta T amount while calculating VACF, instead of using t=10k steps, right?
But what kind of physical or chemical property of my bulk system should be chosen for the rho and A(t) to get tau?
My systems are bulk crystal and amorphous solids inside 3D periodic box.
